# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version, how to debug?

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

I am getting `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version` and if I understood well is a mismatching encryption protocol version in server and client.

I see many solutions like setting `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");`

where this property should be set, on server side or client side?
And how to check which protocol is running both in client and server?

Comment: This kind of error can also happen if the server simply does not speak TLS and its non-TLS response gets wrongly interpreted as TLS. To debug: try with other clients, enable TLS debugging in the client,  look at the traffic with Wireshark, check the configurations at the server side (it is totally unclear what is running here) ... - its complex and there is no simple receipt.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: sorry, no. _OpenSSL_ misdiagnoses plaintext as 'wrong version', but JSSE says '[unsupported or] unrecognized TLS message', and neither of them ever uses '_received alert_' for anything other than a received alert. (Also you mean 'recipe' not 'receipt'.) OP: confirm this is an outgoing connection not incoming (to tomcat)? What Java are you on? How are you attempting this connection: SSLSocket/SSLEngine? HttpsURLConnection? java.net.http.HttpClient? Apache? Something else? Agree with debugging, which is done by setting sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks. (Tried to debug locally, where all works fine, the issue is in production where I have no access)I can see that both server and client say hello with TLSv1.2. What can be wrong in production? In which configuration file I can check SSL in Tomcat? And in client? I confirm is outgoing connection

Comment: Where do you 'see' 1.2? Are you looking at the record and/or message headers for ClientHello and ServerHello? For 1.3 those no longer control the version; you need to look at the supported_versions extension instead. How the versions JSSE uses/offers are selected depends, as I hinted, on what Java you are on and what type of code makes the connection -- although if the same code works in test _to the same server_, then I would first look for differences in the Java version or JRE config.